# remove duplicates in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been working on a query that should :
business logic - show all members who attended  the gym(selected from dropdown) within a specified date range.

Problem encountered -I realised that results shows duplicates of which mustn't , may you please assist.

Below is the query I used.

```
Declare @StartDate datetime = '29 May 2014' 
Declare @EndDate datetime = '29 May 2014' 
DEclare @SiteID INT =14 

Declare @StartTime datetime = '05:00 AM' 
Declare @EndTime datetime = '10:00 PM' 
Declare @Start datetime = cast (@StartDate + ' '+ @StartTime as datetime)
Declare @End datetime = cast(@EndDate + ' ' + @EndTime as datetime )

SELECT isnull(atc.totalaccepted,0) TotalAcceptedVisits,ISNULL(att.TotalOverrideVisits, 0) AS         TotalOverrides,  isnull(att1.TotalOverrideDenieds,0) as TotalDenies, ast.Name as     VisitiedSite, c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName as Name, md.MemRefNo
FROM    Contacts c
inner JOIN  Attendance a on a.ContactGUID = c.GUID
inner JOIN  MemberDetail md on md.ContactGUID = c.GUID
inner JOIN  Sites ast on a.SiteID = ast.ID


OUTER APPLY 
(
SELECT  a1.contactguid,COUNT(*) totalaccepted
FROM    Attendance a1
WHERE   a1.contactguid = c.guid
AND (a1.IsSwipeSuccessful = 1)      
AND a1.accessoverridereasonid IS  NULL 
AND a1.AttendDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End
group by  a1.contactguid
)atc


outer APPLY 
(
SELECT  a2.contactguid, COUNT(*) TotalOverrideVisits
FROM    Attendance a2
WHERE   a2.contactguid = c.guid
And (a.IsSwipeSuccessful = 1)
AND a2.accessoverridereasonid IS NOT NULL 
AND a2.AttendDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End
and (a2.SiteID = @SiteID OR @SiteID = 0)
group by  a2.contactguid
) att


OUTER APPLY 
(
SELECT  a3.contactguid,COUNT(*) TotalOverrideDenieds
FROM    Attendance a3
WHERE   a3.contactguid = c.guid
AND a3.IsSwipeSuccessful = 0
AND     a3.accessoverridereasonid IS  NULL 
AND a3.AttendDate BETWEEN @Start AND @end
group by  a3.contactguid
) att1


where   (a.SiteID = @SiteID OR @SiteID = 0)
and     a.AttendDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End
order by md.MemRefNo
```

Results: as you can see below there are members repeating themselves, I only need to see one row of each member with the number of total visits if any, overrides if any and denied visits if any.

```
TotalAcceptedVisits TotalOverrides  TotalDenies    VisitiedSite Name           memRefNo
1                      0            0          Groblersdal  Jean T          G0030
1                      1            1          Groblersdal  Koky Bakkes     G0032
1                      0            1          Groblersdal  Koky Bakkes G0032
1                      1            1          Groblersdal  Koky Bakkes G0032
1                      0            0          Groblersdal  Naomi Fisher    G0035
1                      0            0          Groblersdal  Arthur Bart G0089
1                      0            0          Groblersdal  Tulinda Swi G0034
1                      1            0          Groblersdal  Devon Mooi  G0008
1                      1            0          Groblersdal  Devon Mooi  G0008
```

Comment: Duplicates are usually removed by the keyword `DISTINCT`. So decide which entries should be unique and distinctly select these. In any way, please provide more details, obtained and expected results, etc. in your question, as it is hardly answerable like this.

Comment: have tried this just now, but am still having the problem, I will keep on trying though

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need something like this:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime = '29 May 2014' 
Declare @EndDate datetime = '29 May 2014' 
DEclare @SiteID INT =14 

Declare @StartTime datetime = '05:00 AM' 
Declare @EndTime datetime = '10:00 PM' 
Declare @Start datetime = cast (@StartDate + ' '+ @StartTime as datetime)
Declare @End datetime = cast(@EndDate + ' ' + @EndTime as datetime )

SELECT CASE WHEN TotalAcceptedVisits > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalAcceptedVisits,
CASE WHEN TotalOverrides > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalOverrides,
CASE WHEN TotalDenies > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalDenies,
VisitiedSite, Name, MemRefNo
FROM 
    (SELECT SUM(isnull(atc.totalaccepted,0)) TotalAcceptedVisits, SUM(ISNULL(att.TotalOverrideVisits, 0)) AS         TotalOverrides,  SUM(isnull(att1.TotalOverrideDenieds,0)) as TotalDenies, ast.Name as     VisitiedSite, c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName as Name, md.MemRefNo
    FROM    Contacts c
    inner JOIN  Attendance a on a.ContactGUID = c.GUID
    inner JOIN  MemberDetail md on md.ContactGUID = c.GUID
    inner JOIN  Sites ast on a.SiteID = ast.ID


    OUTER APPLY 
    (
    SELECT  a1.contactguid,COUNT(*) totalaccepted
    FROM    Attendance a1
    WHERE   a1.contactguid = c.guid
    AND (a1.IsSwipeSuccessful = 1)      
    AND a1.accessoverridereasonid IS  NULL 
    AND a1.AttendDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End
    group by  a1.contactguid
    )atc


    outer APPLY 
    (
    SELECT  a2.contactguid, COUNT(*) TotalOverrideVisits
    FROM    Attendance a2
    WHERE   a2.contactguid = c.guid
    And (a.IsSwipeSuccessful = 1)
    AND a2.accessoverridereasonid IS NOT NULL 
    AND a2.AttendDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End
    and (a2.SiteID = @SiteID OR @SiteID = 0)
    group by  a2.contactguid
    ) att


    OUTER APPLY 
    (
    SELECT  a3.contactguid,COUNT(*) TotalOverrideDenieds
    FROM    Attendance a3
    WHERE   a3.contactguid = c.guid
    AND a3.IsSwipeSuccessful = 0
    AND     a3.accessoverridereasonid IS  NULL 
    AND a3.AttendDate BETWEEN @Start AND @end
    group by  a3.contactguid
    ) att1


    where   (a.SiteID = @SiteID OR @SiteID = 0)
    and     a.AttendDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End
    GROUP BY atc.totalaccepted, att.TotalOverrideVisits, att1.TotalOverrideDenieds, ast.Name, c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName, md.MemRefNo) TB
ORDER BY MemRefNo
```

Since, you don't want the SUM of the values, then you can do something as above which basically embeds your SELECT as a subquery and then has a CASE statement to see whether the Total Values is greater than 0, if so return 1 else 0.

Comment: HI Samoan Thanx for your efforts, unfortunately I tried that before, it does eliminate the duplicates yes, but don't solve the problem because it returns the sum of the duplicates, for e.g for Koky Bakes will have 3 accepted visits, 2 overrides and 3 denies

Comment: Hey mate, I've updated my answer so it should no longer return the sum and will only return 1 or 0. I think this is what you're after?

Comment: Now that's more like it, thank you so much it look like this is a winner, with little editing on the group by clause  when grouping by everything I want to see still has duplicates so I grouped by name, ast.name and memrefno, and one other thing don't forget to name your table, that tiny mistake can make a programmer crazy. but thank you so much u thee bomb

Comment: Cool, I've updated it to give an alias to the derived table; so if that has solved your problem, please mark my answer above as the solution :)